# Default service account not working with kubernetes plugin on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have configured the Kubernetes plugin to spin up slaves.
However I am having problems with access-control. 
Getting an error when the master tries to spin up new pods (slaves)

> Unexpected exception encountered while provisioning agent Kubernetes Pod Template
>   io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/namespaces/npd-test/pods. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked..
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:315)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:266)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:237)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:230)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:208)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:643)
>       at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:300)
>       at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud$ProvisioningCallback.call(KubernetesCloud.java:636)
>       at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud$ProvisioningCallback.call(KubernetesCloud.java:581)
>       at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have checked the access of the default service account located at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` and tried to create a pod in `https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/namespaces/npd-test/pods.` using the token and it works.

Not sure why the plugin is complaining that the service account does not have access.

I have tried configuring the Kubernetes plugin with None credentials and a Kubernetes Service Account Credential (no way to specify account), but neither works.

Comment: Do you have RBAC enabled?

Comment: you can check it using `kubectl cluster-info dump | grep authorization-mode`

Answer (score 3):

It is odd that the service account worked for you normally but didn't work in Jenkins. In my setup, I had to add a `RoleBinding` to give the service account the `edit` role (my namespace is actually `jenkins` but I changed it here to match your namespace).

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: npd-test
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: edit
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: npd-test
```

After I did that, I configured the Kubernetes Cloud plugin like this and it works for me.

```
Kubernetes URL: https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Kubernetes server certificate key:
Disable https certificate check: off
Kubernetes Namespace: npd-test
Credentials: - none -
```

Answer (score 0):

The following creates a Service account to build from a the namespace **jenkins** to the namespace **build**. I omitted the rules but if you need them I can add them too.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins

---

kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: build

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
  namespace: build
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
```